# Duplicate Firestore subcollection created upon updating existing records with Google App Script Extension

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Google App Script extension to import my existing Data/rows from Google sheet by using this well-written library - https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript

I tried to use *firestore.updateDocument* function to update existing documents within the Firestore that are identified by a set of primary keys, after comparing them to the existing rows in googlesheets.

The code, which is based on Javascript, I believe, works to identify existing documents before the update function runs, but it actually - results in creating a "subcollection project" in the target collection instead. This results in an issue where my app is not able to retrieve latest updated records but only the original outdated Firestore documents.

Kindly refer to the screenshot.

[image]

I followed library instructions and everything, could someone who is good at javascript look into my code and guide me?

```
   var collectionName = "collectionNameTest"

       // Check if a document with the same primary keys exists in the existing Firestore collection
       var duplicateDocs = firestore.query(collectionName)
       .Where(primaryKey1Column,"==",primaryKey1)
       .Where(primaryKey2Column,"==",primaryKey2)
       .Execute();

 if (duplicateDocs.length > 0) {
         // A document with the same primary key already exists in the collection

        const name = duplicateDocs[0].name

         console.log(`Documents with primaryKey1 '${primaryKey1}' and with primaryKey2 '${primaryKey2}'  already exists. Updating existing record with new record...`);

         try { var result = firestore.updateDocument(`${collectionName}/${name}`, data);
                console.log("Firestore document updated, Firestore result: ", result);
              } catch (e) {
                console.error("Firestore update failed: ", e);
              }                 

       } else {
         // No document with the same primary key exists, so create a new document
         var result = firestore.createDocument(collectionName, data);
         console.log("New Firestore document created, Firestore result: ", result);
       }
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, I proposed a modification point. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: My God!! It worked!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
const name = duplicateDocs[0].name
```

#### To:

```
const name = duplicateDocs[0].name.split("/").pop();
```

#### Note:

- In this case, it supposes that `data` is a valid value. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Updating Documents of Firestore for Google Apps Scripts](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript#updating-documents)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it worked like a charm. I am an iOS developer purely and I don't know much about Javascript. While I will check the reference you posted, would you mind if you can explain the code changes to me, and why it actually worked!

Comment: @Michael Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `const name = duplicateDocs[0].name.split("/").pop()`, when I saw [the repository](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript#updating-documents), it seems that `name` is `FirstCollection/FirstDocument`. When I saw your question, I confirmed `projects`. From this situation, I guessed that in your situation `name` might be `{collectionName}/projects/###/###,,,`. Also, when I tested your script in my environment, I confirmed the same situation.

Comment: @Michael In this case, `duplicateDocs[0].name` is like `projects/###/databases/###/documents/{collectionName}/{name}`. So, in order to retrieve the last value of `{name}`, I modified it to `duplicateDocs[0].name.split("/").pop()`. `split("/")` splits the value by `/`. And, `pop()` returns the last element of the array. By this, `{name}` is retrieved from `projects/###/databases/###/documents/{collectionName}/{name}`. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Michael As additional information, in my proposed modification, I modified your showing script. If the value of `${collectionName}/${name}` is directly retrieved from `duplicateDocs[0].name`, I think that `duplicateDocs[0].name.split("/").slice(-2).join("/")` might also be able to be used. By this, `{collectionName}/{name}` is retrieved.

Comment: I am so grateful for your complete explanation. I now understand the reason why the script created a separate project and so on. I don't know how to thank you further. I now understand all the modification and code, love that pop()!

Comment: @Michael Thank you for replying. About `pop`, you can see the document at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop